# Confused about linking an interactive element Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a website for my coursework, but I've gotten a bit stuck. I'm trying to hyperlink the images that I've put inside of what is basically a carousel (although done very weirdly, I'm told). My code is below.
**JavaScript**:

```
  function ChangeImageLoop(button_id) {
        var image = document.getElementById('Banner' + n);
        if (button_id = "Right") {
            n += 1;
        } else {
            n -= 1;
        }
        if (n > MaxN) {
            n = 1
        }
        if (n < 1) {
            n = 3
        }
        image.src = "Fancy Dress Banner " + n + ".png";
        image.id = "Banner" + n;
    }
```

And the **HTML**:

```
<div class="Content">
    <div class="ImageSlide"> <a href="Costumes.html">
        <img id="Banner1" src="Fancy Dress Banner 1.png" alt="Musical Fancy Dress">
    </a>

    </div>
    <div class="ImageLeft">
        <button type="button" id="Left" onclick='ChangeImageLoop2(id)' style="width:30px; height:18px;"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="LeftRightGap"></div>
    <div class="ImageRight">
        <button type="button" id="Right" onclick='ChangeImageLoop(id)' style="width:30px; height:18px;"></button>
    </div>
```

Don't think it's relevant, but here's the **CSS** just in case:

```
.ImageSlide {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-left:2%;
    margin-right:2%;
    background:#BCD6D6;
    border:2px solid black;
}
.ImageLeft {
    width:5%;
    height:2%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:3%;
    margin-top:1%;
    background:#BCD6D6;
    border:2px solid black;
}
.LeftRightGap {
    width:80%;
    height:2%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:2%;
    margin-top:1%;
    background:#BCD6D6;
    border:2px solid black;
}
.ImageRight {
    width:5%;
    height:2%;
    float:right;
    margin-right:3%;
    margin-top:1%;
    background:#BCD6D6;
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

I've tried a few different things, but I cant figure out how I would retrieve the contents of the 'href=""' section and change it, as each image needs to hyperlink to a different page of the site. If anyone could help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: On the buttons, you call `onclick='ChangeImageLoop(id)'`, but what is `id` ?

Comment: @Don'tVoteMeDown id is just something I forgot to remove; I was originally trying to write a single function to rotate my carousel in both directions, but it ended up being too complicated and I just wrote two different functions, one for each button. id was what I was using to identify whether the button pressed was the left or the right one.

Comment: Do you know jQuery? If not, you should check it out, it's awesome!
With it, you could do something like `$('a').attr('href')` to get the attribute and `$('a').attr('href', newHref)` to set the attribute